# BOOTx64.EFI file boots but only directly, not when UEFI is directed to the external SSD

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, uefi

I have an external SSD with Arch Linux on it. The ESP is mounted to /boot. On the ESP, I have the directory EFI and in that, there is a BOOT directory. I created a BOOTx64.EFI using an /ext/kernel/cmdline that says \vmlinuz-linux root=PARTUUID=[partuuid] initd=\initramfs-linux.img.

My thought is that when I use the Boot list and select my SSD, the UEFI system will automatically find /boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI and correctly boot. But instead, I am dropped to the rootfs and I have to mount /dev/sda2 (the root partition) to new_root and then exit rootfs. And the boot works. But /proc/cmdline in that case shows YRY.

Alternatively, if I tell the boot list to boot from a file and select the BOOTx64.EFI file, it boots perfectly and /proc/cmdline shows my /etc/kernel/cmdline.

So I think that the HP Elitebook is correctly trying to run BOOTx64.EFI when I select the SSD, but for some reason, it doesn't see the root partiion (says device is '' and filesystem doesn't exist). So I have to manually mount it and then all is well.

I'm hoping to figure out why the laptop doesn't mount my root partition to new_root when I invoke the EFI from SSD, but does when I invoke it from the EFI file directly.

Comment: Does the command line include `initd=`, as written in the question, or `initrd=`? Partition can be not recognized by the kernel either because the kernel module supporting its fstype or device is not loaded (initrd), or udev has not created `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/*` (so again initrd).

Comment: Actually, since writing the question, I amended things. The /etc/kernel/cmdline now how no initrd (which is what it had...not initd...typo). Instead, I put the initramfs line in the linux.preset file and redid mkinitcpio --uefi ...--cmdline /etc/kerne/cmdline. That cmdline now has only \vmlinuz-linux and the root=PARTUUID=... with rw and nowatchdog at the end. The BOOTx64.EFI created with the linux.preset behaves in exactly the same way as before. Trying to boot from the device (SSD) shown in the boot list drops me to the rootfs. Directly booting from the file itself is fine.

Comment: BTW: On a much older Dell Inspiron (with UEFI, of course), it all works perfectly. Select the device from the boot list and it boot. Select the file, and it boots. I suspect, therefore, that the problem is with either the HP Elitebook iteration of the UEFI or the fact that the HP internal drives are nvme, not /dev/sda or whatever. The reason I don't use the /dev/sda parition designation in the EFI file is that I want to be able to use this external SSD on any computer...including ones like the Dell, where the hard drive is /dev/sda.

Comment: Are you saying that the 'early hook' udev is not getting the chance to recognize the root? But why does it work correctly when I tell HP to boot directly from the BOOTx64.EFI file? Incidentally, I also can boot by dropping into the UEFI shell and running an nsh file. In that, I have the one line like the old /etc/kernel/cmdline line (vmlinuz, root by partuuid, and initrd img file. And it works perfectly.

Comment: What boot manager are you using? What are `/ext/kernel/cmdline` and `/etc/kernel/cmdline` and how is `BOOTx64.EFI` "created" by them? mkinitcpio only creates the initrd (`initramfs-*.img`).

Comment: If you are using EFISTUB and hardcoding kernel command line, it could be that this method of specifying the kernel command line has some interaction with initrd, especially with regards to referring to partitions indirectly by PARTUUID. Try setting, for example `root=/dev/sdXY`, replacing `XY` as appropriate for your root partition. This could be specific to your hardware as well. **Edit:** Also try setting `rootdelay=[some value in seconds]`, for example `rootdelay=2`. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=rootdelay

Comment: I'm not using a boot manager. Please pardon my typos: 'ext' was 'etc'. BOOTx64.EFI is created by running mkinitcpio with the option --uefi (which creates an EFI file) and the option --cmdline (which directs it to use the /etc/kernel/cmdline file when making the EFI file). That EFI file can then be used to boot. UEFI runs EFI files. If, for example, direct your computer to run the shell.efi file, you will be dropped into a UEFI shell. From there, you can run nsh files or efi files. But the UEFI specification says that, by default, if the UEFI system is started without a bootloader

Comment: and given a drive to boot, it will look for a specific efi file: /boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI. That's why my system is trying to boot it when I choose the extternal SSD. That file is valid and boots (I know this, because it works when I run it directly, either from the boot list or from within the UEFI shell). For some reason, though, when the system tries to run it after I select the SSD drive, it drops me into a rootfs prompt. From there, I can manually mount the root drive and the system boots. Using root=/dev/sdXY is not an option, because the sdXY changes for an external drive, depending on

Comment: what the hard drive is designated. In my HP, for example, the hard drives are /dev/nvmeXYZ. So the external drive is /dev/sda. But in the Dell, the hard drive is /dev/sda. So the external drive is /dev/sdb. I have tried the rootdelay=10, and it didn't change anything for me.

Comment: This difference between the device names could be a clue to the cause of the problem. The two computers "see" the SSD differently. initrd drops the user to a prompt when it cannot find the specified root device for whatever reason. I gave some of the possible reasons above, but things to try when troubleshooting also include updating firmware and checking UEFI settings for SSD. Also see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive#Troubleshooting

Comment: I agree that the problem is likely related to the SSD (as opposed to a USB) and the HP firmware. I am reluctant to update firmware on the HP, but might give it a try. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

CAUTION: This is not for newbies or people who are just getting to know Arch Linux. YOU RISK LOSING EVERYTHING ON YOUR DRIVE IF YOU MAKE SOME KIND OF MISTAKE. AT A MINIMUM, PLEASE BACK UP ALL DATA BEFORE EXPLORING THIS OPTION.

I finally learned how to do this correctly. Best approach, I think, is to use the systemd-auto-gpt-generator. This is a part of systemd and it is designed to find and mount partitions based on their GPT type. In order for it to work, the first step is to make sure that your GTP types are correct: EFI for your EFI partition (EF00 code), Linux-x64-root (8304 code) for your root partition, and Home (8302), if you use a separate home partition.

The next step is to set your hooks in mkinitcpio.conf to start with systemd, and not base and udev. In other words, replace base and udev with systemd in the hooks line of the configuration file.

At this point, you're ready to make the efi boot file: mkinitcpio --uefi /boot/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI

Once completed, the selecting your external drive from the boot menu will automatically work, mounting the root partition and the home partition. The boot partition will not be mounted until you try to access files on it. At that point, the system will automatically mount it.